# how rewrite url from subfolder at root

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I have more link in Google es:

```
http://www.mysite.com/blog/23-08-2012/example.html
http://www.mysite.com/blog/more/
http://www.mysite.com/blog/test/example.html
```

how to rewrite the url by removing the word "blog" in htaccess es:

```
http://www.mysite.com/23-08-2012/example.html
http://www.mysite.com/more/
http://www.mysite.com/test/example.html
```

---

## EDIT

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

## RE-EDIT solution

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(.*)$ /$1
```

it is important to put this line at the end, not the beginning

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(.*)$ /$1
```

Comment: @Nerd-Herd I already use this script
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need mod_alias to do this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(.*)$ /$1
```

You can use that in your vhost config or the htaccess file in your document root.

---

Surprise that you don't have mod_alias, it's pretty much loaded on default. But since you're already using mod_rewrite:

If this is what you have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then above the `RewriteBase`, add this:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I do not have mod_alias, is a simple website inside aruba

Answer (score 1):

Just a minute or two to read [Apache's Rewrite Rule](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs/httpexamplecomfilehtml-to-httpexamplecomfolder1fil) documentation would've provided you with answer. Here's an outline to what you can do:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ^blog/
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```